# Can a point have a path to itself?

Tags: general-topology

In Topology by Munkres a path is defined as

> Given points $x$ and $y$ of the space $X$, a path in $X$ from $x$ to
> $y$ is a continuous map $f:[a,b] \rightarrow X$ of some closed
> interval in the real line into $X$, such that $f(a)=x$ and $f(b)=y$.

My question is if it is possible to have a path from $x$ to $x$. I think if we let $f$ to map $[a,b]$ on $x$, then $f(a)=x$ and $f(b)=x$. Is this argument correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's just a loop. That is the central object of study in Algebraic Topology.

Comment: Yes, as  an example you consider the constant map with value $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. Such paths are known as loops and play very important role in the algebraic topology.